# watching a directory in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filesystemwatcher

We have an application that needs to process incoming files that are dropped into a directory.
I am looking for the best way to do this.

We have been using a looping Backgroundrb process, but, to be honest Backgroundrb is unreliable and we'd like to move away from it if possible.

Delayed_job doesn't seem to be for ongoing tasks but for one offs.

I've found DirectoryWatcher http://codeforpeople.rubyforge.org/directory_watcher/ which looks promising, but ideally we want to have some control over this and also be able to monitor if it is up or not.

So the requirements are:

- run forever
- process files in order
- be monitorable
- have some sort of way of restarting it and ensuring it is up (God?)

Thanks for any input! This shouldn't be difficult and I am surprised I can't find someone else talking about this on the web as I would have thought that in business applications this was not uncommon.

Comment: https://github.com/ttilley/fssm

Comment: https://github.com/guard/listen This is new replace FSSM project

Answer (score 13, accepted):

And there's also [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard):

> Guard automates various tasks by running custom rules whenever file or directories are modified.
>
> It's frequently used by software developers, web designers, writers and other specialists to avoid mundane, repetitive actions and commands such as "relaunching" tools after changing source files or configurations.
>
> Common use cases include: an IDE replacement, web development tools, designing "smart" and "responsive" build systems/workflows, automating various project tasks and installing/monitoring various system services...

Comment: If all you need are file system notifications, then Guard's sub-project __listen__ might offer more fine grained control: http://rubygems.org/gems/listen

Answer (score 16):

Thanks [@emerge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1470205/emerge), as a relative newbie to rails I wanted to watch for files in my Rails app and not from the command line. Compared to the other options here, found that [**Listen**](https://github.com/guard/listen) was an incredibly simple 2 steps:

1. Added this to the gem file:

   ```
   gem 'listen', '~> 2.0'
   ```
2. Then added this in Application.rb to execute on app startup:

   ```
   listener = Listen.to('public/json_import') do |added| 
     puts "added absolute path: #{added}"
   end
   listener.start # not blocking
   ```

We can also listen to multiple dirs, and also modify/add/remove:

```
listener = Listen.to('dir/to/listen', 'dir/to/listen2') do |modified, added, removed|
```

Answer (score 9):

There's also the tiny filewatcher rubygem. The gem has no dependencies, contains no platform specific code and simply detects updates, delitions and additions by polling.

```
require 'filewatcher'

FileWatcher.new(["directory"]).watch() do |filename, event|
  if(event == :changed)
    puts "File updated: " + filename
  end
  if(event == :delete)
    puts "File deleted: " + filename
  end
  if(event == :new)
    puts "Added file: " + filename
  end
end
```

Comment: `filewatcher` is good but does not work well if you upload a set of files all at once by SFTP to a directory (some of the new files are not being detected). That's why I use `rb-inotify` for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Three old-school options that I know of:

**Ara T. Howard's DirWatch:**

- Docs: http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/dirwatch/dirwatch-0.9.0/README
- Download: http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/dirwatch/dirwatch-0.9.0.tgz

**My own DirectoryWatcher:**

- Docs: http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/rdoc/files/DirectoryWatcher_rb.html
- Download: http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/DirectoryWatcher.rb

**Paul Horman's FileSystemWatcher:**

- Docs: http://paulhorman.com/filesystemwatcher/
- Download: http://paulhorman.com/filesystemwatcher/FileSystemWatcher.1.0.0.zip

Answer (score 2):

I think https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify should work for you. 
An example to use this gem

```
require 'rb-inotify'
notifier = INotify::Notifier.new
notifier.watch("/tmp", :moved_to, :create) do |event|
    puts "#{event.absolute_name} is now in path /tmp!"
end
notifier.run
```

Comment: This gem is perfect, and still maintained after all this time

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mynyml/watchr

That's typically used for running unit test automatically but should suit your needs too.