# setInterval() equivalent for ruby

Tags: ruby

In JavaScript you can do:

```
setInterval(func,delay);
```

I can't seem to find anything on google for what I'm actually looking for.
Is there a ruby equivalent for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791964/how-do-i-make-a-ruby-script-run-once-a-second has the same question asked.
This gem [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) might help you

Answer (score 18):

You can do something like it:

```
Thread.new do
  loop do 
    sleep delay
    # your code here
  end
end
```

Or you can define a function:

```
# @return [Thread] return loop thread reference
def set_interval(delay)
  Thread.new do
    loop do
      sleep delay
      yield # call passed block
    end
  end
end
```

When you want to stop the `set_interval`, you just call any of these methods: `exit`, `stop` or `kill`.

You can test it into console (`irb` or `pry`):

```
t1 = Time.now; t = set_interval(2.5) {puts Time.now - t1}
> 2.500325
> 5.000641
> 7.500924
...
t.kill # stop the set_interval function
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler):

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
scheduler.every '5m' do
    # Some Fancy Code Logic That Runs Every 5 Minutes
end
```

Comment: Great call, though `Rufus::Scheduler#interval` may be more appropriate if you need the same fixed time delay as the JS `setInterval` https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#in-at-every-interval-cron