# Ruby Thread not sleeping but finished

Tags: ruby, thread-sleep

I have coded something in ruby. Now, I want to make it so that every 3 seconds that code runs again. I have looked at threading. I built a thread and I put a

```
while true do end
```

loop inside it. Also I make it sleep for 3 seconds. Take a look

```
Thread.new do 
while true do
#code 
end
sleep 3
end
```

My problem is that when I run my code it doesn't run it at all and it doesn't repeat.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
Thread.new do
  loop do 
    sleep 3000
    # your code here
  end
end
```

[Courtesy of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19416686/1527705).

Comment: same things happen or to be more exact : Nothing happens :(